# Dynamically created XAML not displaying custom font

Tags: xaml, printing, resources, fonts

I am dynamically generating XAML which has a reference to a resource custom font.
When pushing this xaml into an xps the font is not printing.

I suspect this is because I am working with a stream of xaml, instead of xaml that comes from a file.

How can I get this resource reference to work when streaming xaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment there is no solution for this.  My workaround was to dynamically generate an image of the text and font and then streaming that image directly into the XAML document.

Ugly as sin, but it works.